# to come at the day

Tags: traduction

This is part of a document about mindfulness.
There is that very peculiar phrasing :

"Instead consider it a way to mix things up a bit, a different approach and a fresh way to come at the day."

Am I right to understand "to come at the day" as : "aborder/entamer/accueillir la journée" ?

Comment: You are absolutly right.

Comment: I am quite OK with that. I would pick between aborder and entamer - though accueillir is pretty nice in this context, source does not include such positive emotion (ie welcome this day).

Comment: To add a quick remark: Note that "come at the day" is not a fixed expression since "come at" can appear in many phrases, and generally means "approach" (indeed in the sense of *aborder*). A common collocation is "come at ___ from a different angle".

Answer (score 2):

On utilise aussi volontiers 'attaquer' :
 "une approche différente et  novatrice  pour attaquer la journée."